# Array comparison doesnt work

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I have a working array comparison (tested with different kind of code), which looks like this:

```js
var a = [0,1,2]
var b = [1,2]

var match = []
var miss = []

func(a,b, match, miss);

function func(a, b, matches, misses) {  
  for (var i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<a.length; j++) { 
      if (b[i] == a[j]) {
        console.log("Found");
        matches.push(b[i])
      } 
    }
  }
  console.log("Matches: " + matches); 
  console.log("Misses: " + misses);
}
```

It works usually fine. However this time it doesn't. I have two arrays which have a different size (a is bigger than b) and can have different content like "100.AB 12345".

I can't explain why my function doesn't work in that case. Can someone help me out? It doesn't find any matches, everything is a miss, even though they are matches.

Comment: The above code is working fine right. It outputs matches array as 1,2 which is expected. Which usecase your code is failing?

Comment: I have two arrays, which I get from different systems. They both look like this: firstArray:  100.AF 027731,100.AF 027755,100.AF 027925, etc. secondArray: 210.AF 000062,150.AF 005909,132.AF 183654 etc.

Somehow the code doesnt work with this...is the type important maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's this line:

```
if (b[j] == a[j])
```

Should the `b[j]` be `b[i]`? As `a` is bigger than `b`, using the `j` indexer would be attempting to reference after the end of `b`.

Comment: IYou´re right. However I changed it by mistake. It was b[i], so it´s not a solution to my problem. But thank you for the note.

Answer (score 0):

Hello check the below code it will work fine even a is bigger than b or b is bigger than a

```js
var a = ['a','ab','c','d','e'];
var b = ['ef','f','ab','a'];
var a1,b1;
var match = [];
var miss = [];
var temp_a=a.length;
var temp_b=b.length;
if( temp_a > temp_b){
 a1=b;
  b1=a;
}else{
 a1=a;
 b1=b;
}
func(a1,b1, match, miss);

function func(a, b, matches, misses) {  
  for (var i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
   for (var j=0; j<a.length; j++) { 
    if (b[i] == a[j]) {
     console.log("Found");
     matches.push(b[i])
    } 
   }
  }
 console.log("Matches: " + matches); 
 console.log("Misses: " + misses);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. Code looks fine and works. However, when using in the example where my code above doesnt work as well, your code doesnt work too. Is it possible that the array has to be a string type?

Comment: check the edited code for string format also it will work fine